# GLSL equivalent for sampler_state?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In HLSL i can set what kind of filtering i want to use for each sampler using smth like:

```
sampler mySampler= 
sampler_state
{
    Texture = <myTexture>;
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
    MinFilter = LINEAR;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
};
```

is there an equivalent in GLSL (4.2)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are sampler objects. But they are created in client side with C API, not in GLSL shader. When you bind them to specific texture unit, sampler object overrides texture paremeters from texture bound to this unit.

See GL spec: http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec42.core.20120119.pdf (page 208, section 3.9.2)

Comment: +1 But the actual answer should be No, instead of Yes, as you yourself explained that there is no equivalent in GLSL.